# Android Kotlin - clear glide cache in background thread doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, android-glide, android-background

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    Glide.with(this@UploadProfileImage).clearDiskCache()
}
```

I get `unresolved reference` on `clearDiskCache`

When I do

```
Glide.with(this).clearDiskCache()
```

instead then I don't get unresolved reference on clearDiskCache but

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun with(activity: Activity): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(fragment: android.app.Fragment): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(context: Context): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(view: View): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(fragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(activity: FragmentActivity): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
```

on `with`

Comment: Where do you call `Glide.with(this).clearDiskCache()`? In Activity/Fragment/...  ?

Comment: In Activity, I also tried in the App class

Comment: what is 'UploadProfileImage' that 'this@UploadProfileImage' is referring to?

Comment: It's the activity

Comment: you should use 'get' instead of 'with'. is there any reason you dont use 'get'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use 'Glide.get(context)' instead of 'Glide.with(context)' to use 'clearDiskCache' method.

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks!